# Flex 4 -- Adding blur below pane

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm looking to create a component like an Alert but with a bunch of components inside the pane. How can I create the blur effect below a pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [AS docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#filters), there's a good example that will do what you want. Any DisplayObject can have filters applied to it

Alternatively, you can use something like TweenMax's dropShadowFilter to do it quickly and easily